# Why is Account name exportable in bulk api but not billingaddress?

Tags: bulk-api, compound-fields

From what I read online compound fields are not exportable using bulk export.

`services/data/v58.0/query/?q=SELECT DurableId, IsCompound FROM FieldDefinition where EntityDefinitionId='Account' AND IsCompound = true`

Above request returns:

```
{
    "totalSize": 2,
    "done": true,
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "FieldDefinition",
                "url": "/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/FieldDefinition/Account.Name"
            },
            "DurableId": "Account.Name",
            "IsCompound": true
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "FieldDefinition",
                "url": "/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/FieldDefinition/Account.BillingAddress"
            },
            "DurableId": "Account.BillingAddress",
            "IsCompound": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't get any error if I include Account.Name in bulk query, but I get following error if I include BillingAddress.

`Failed to process query: FUNCTIONALITY_NOT_ENABLED: Selecting compound data not supported in Bulk Query`

Why is this happening, how do I identify which fields can be included in Bulk API?

Comment: I think the error tells you the reason directly. The Account Name field is a simple text value, but the Billing Address is a compound field consisting of Billing Street, Billing City, Billing Postal Code etc. Export the individual fields instead of the compound value.

Comment: But Account name is also being returned when I query for compound field

Comment: While Contact Name is a compound, Account name is not AFAIK. What do you mean by your comment?

Comment: Account name is compound in two independent instances, at least according to the API call that I'm making, I don't think it is coincidence.
Still trying to figure out what fields are allowed in bulk fetch.